How to Run, Develop and Deploy Legacy ASP.NET Project On New Windows 11?
I have the original source code for the project and am trying to get it up and running locally on Windows 11, but I'm not sure what tools(and versions) I need.
Additional Information:
The project was originally created with the old Visual Studio 2010 in ASP.NET 4.8 (.NET 4.0).
Atm project is running on IIS 8.5/Windows Server 2012 R2/Microsoft Sql Server 2012
Tried to download Visual Studio 2010, but it seems that it's no longer supported and available for download. Even if I manage to download it, I'm not sure if it will work on Windows 11.

first step is download and install Visual Studio 2022.  (It should be able to migrate the project file)  .NET Framework 4.8 is available in Windows 11.  Any SDKs you need can be installed via Visual Studio.  I've done this in the past and it was a pretty simple process.  (though that was a desktop app without any SQL server dependency)

To work with that site, then before you try to load and work on the site, make sure you install the webforms parts for vs2022. They are still available, but not installed by default.
So, tools->Get Tools and features.
Then, you want to select all of what I have here:

Next up, you don't mention if you have
"a asp.net web site"
or
"a asp.net web site application"
The main difference between the above 2 types, is that for the web site, then you go file->open web site and browse to the folder and select it.
Hopefully, the project is the above 2nd type, and thus you can go file->open project, and browse to that folder and select the .sln file.
So, make sure you installed all of the above workflows in Visual Studio.
Of course, I assume you have the main asp.net workflow selected. That would be this one:

So, hopefully you have the .sln file used to create this project.
Note that when using an "application", then taking the source files from the web site will NOT suffice, as during publishing, all source code files and code behind files are pre-compiled, and stripped out at publish time.
So, rather important to have the original source code site and project, and not attempt to use what was published to the server.
I am currently using vs2022 on a number of web sites, and some date back to the 2010 time frame, and such projects work fine with vs2022 after having installed the above workflows.
